# Delay in sidebar animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> I do not know if I can link to the theme that has the problem that I
>   want to solve. If it is not allowed, please tell me to delete the
>   question

I'm using this theme:
[here](http://pages.revox.io/dashboard/3.0.0/html/condensed/index.html)
And as you can see, whenever the cursor is on the sidebar, it expands. How can I make the sidebar only get bigger when the cursor is on the sidebar for at least 2 seconds? That a delay occurs before the animation.

Is there any part in the javascripts used by the theme where I can define this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of CSS will do it.

To delay only the opening:

```css
.sidebar-visible .icon-thumbnail,
.sidebar-visible .page-sidebar,
body.sidebar-visible .page-sidebar .sidebar-header .sidebar-header-controls {
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

---

To delay both opening and closing:

```css
.icon-thumbnail,
.page-sidebar,
.page-sidebar .sidebar-header .sidebar-header-controls,
body.sidebar-visible .page-sidebar .sidebar-header .sidebar-header-controls {
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

**Note** this CSS has to be loaded after theme's to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

When the user hovers the sidebar, start a timeout, at the end of the timeout, check if they are still hovering the sidebar. If so, call the function to pop out the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try use jquery 
.mouseout();

for example:

```
$("p").mouseout(function(){
    $("p").delay(5000).hide(1000);
});
```